# Drupal 7 - View block is not getting displayed in entity field builder

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-blocks

I have created one view of display type block.
but it is not getting displayed in entity field builder.

```
 Below is module we are using - 
 https://www.drupal.org/project/efb
```

I am attaching my view image.
Is it permission issue ?

Expected behavior is chronological view should be listed but it is not showing.

1) View

[image]

2) entity field builder module (installed)

[image]

3) Edit view of homepage (In which i have clicked on add content of entity field. Expected behavior is chronological view should be listed here but it is not showing.

[image]